# How to search a table using Ruby Gem ActiveRecord, Sinatra and Postgres

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, sinatra

How to make a word search using Ruby Gem ActiveRecord, Sinatra and Postgres?

My table looks like so:

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "body"
  t.string   "image_url"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

and I'm trying to search for key words in title AND body fields.

Using the [ActiveRecord Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) I tried `Post.find_by(body: "a")` but got an empty result where my body do contain the char **a**

I know in Rails you'll do something like so:

```
  Post.where(["body LIKE :tag", {:tag => word}])
```

but I can't figure out how to do the same using Sinatra and Postgres.

Comment: What form has your trying taken so far? Please post code, even if it is incomplete, and show where you are stuck. That gives a better idea of how best to help you.

Comment: @NeilSlater I updated my question. Hope it shows what I did try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at tsearch for postgres.  http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/tsearch/V2/

This is a very simple search.  Lots of options are available, for instance, weighting matches in the title more than matches in the body.

You would add a vector column to your table:

```
 ALTER TABLE posts ADD COLUMN vector tsvector;
```

Then

```
 UPDATE posts SET vector=('default',coalesce(title,'') ||' '|| coalesce(body,''));
 VACUUM FULL ANALYZE;
```

Then you can query:

```
 SELECT * FROM posts WHERE vector @@ to_tsquery('default', 'Test | Zeppelin');
```

Comment: Thanks John. Looks strait forward however I'm trying to avoid adding more gems to my app.

Comment: Its actually not a gem, its a postgres extension.  There may be gem wrappers, but I've just used native SQL as above after the extension is installed.  There are lots of options to tsearch and it is quite powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a method that will do this job however, running raw SQL using the ActiveRecord Gem did  pull the trick:

```
Post.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%word%' OR body LIKE '%word%';")
```

Hope it will help someone sometime...